# help me take my decision about adding Exchange server to the company

Tags: exchange

I work in small company with about 40 employees, we have domain controller with active directory, and we are thinking of adding an exchange server but there are some questions we need to ask before we make the decision.

Is it worth our company adding our own exchange server?

what are the requirments that must be ready before getting the exchange server?

what are the advantages and disadvantages of getting our own server or using hosted exchange services?

Comment: Not nearly enough information to allow somebody to realistically answer this question. You could start by including some information about your current configuration? Do you even have Active Directory?

Answer (score 3):

From a purely technical standpoint, this is largely impossible to answer without further background knowledge. Nevertheless, I would guess that when you have to ask questions like that, your technical expertise is limited, so my recommendation would be to go with a hosted service, as running  complicated system like Exchange is non-trivial.